# wireguard VPN configuration

Tags: windows, vpn, configuration, router, wireguard

I have a wireguard vpn configuration on my router, the ports are open and the server  configuration I think is correct.

however when I want to connect a client, it only shows me this error:
[TUN] [client1] Handshake for peer 1 (mi ip:51820) did not complete after 5 seconds retrying (try 2),
It is the only error that reproduces, I put the configuration of the client and server:

Client configuration

```
[Interface]
Private Key 1 
Address = 10.0.0.2/32
DNS = 64.6.64.6

[Peer]
Public Key 1 
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = 189.141.56.60:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

config servers

```
option local_ip '10.0.0.1'
option local_port '51820'
option local_ipv6 'fd00:db8:0:abc::1'
option private key 2
option public key 1
option access 'ACCEPT'
option enable '1'
```

config peers 'wg_peer_5088'

```
option name 'wir'
option client_key 
option private_key
option client_ip '10.0.0.2/32'
option public key 2
```

- The server configuration is generated automatically because the router is compatible with wireguard, only the client is being configured*

If somebody please, has so kind to help to resolve this issues i will appreciate.

Comment: `the VPS configuration is correct` - what VPS? to ensure you are using the correct keys, can you perhaps replace the `#############` with `key 1`, `key 2` etc, just so we can see which key you use where

Comment: yeah, that's not what I said to do, because now you've exposed your keys

Comment: you've got 7 lots of  `#####` some of those would need to match others - all I said was instead of `####` in the question put `key 1`, `key 2` etc - i.e. **EDIT THE QUESTION** and make it more understandable

Comment: OK, I'll edit the question, to make it more understandable